# Implement admob ads using expo

Tags: react-native, expo, admob

I'm trying to implement react-native-google-mobile-ads using react native and expo. I configured my app with **app.config.js** to use env variables.

Unfortunately I got the error message:

> Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/
> • should NOT have additional property 'react-native-android-mobile-ads'.

The implementation using only app.json works fine, see https://medium.com/react-native-expo/migrate-expo-ads-admob-to-react-native-google-mobile-ads-3747b3a3b75e

Anyone knows the answer?

Thanks

Comment: I put the react-native-android-mobile-ads part in the app.json file and the expo part in the app.config.js for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone who might get here during debugging: I believe it might have been a problem of putting AdMob properties into `app.json / expo / react-native-android-mobile-ads` instead of `app.json / react-native-android-mobile-ads` (top level).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, having it defined in an app.json is not a very good option since I'm using seperate bundleId for dev/prod build of my app and that appId is tied to the bundleId :/

I'm thinking I'll need to just create a script to generate an app.json from the app.config.js

My current solution is this

```js
// app.config.js

const config = { ... }; // Your expo config

// create a json version of this file to satisfy "react-native-google-mobile-ads"
fs.writeFileSync('./app.json', JSON.stringify(config, undefined, 2), { encoding: 'utf-8' })

module.exports = config;
```